# sencha touch commercial license cost

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

what is the cost of sencha touch commercial license

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you gone through the Sencha website? You should read the [licensing details here](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/license/). And the cost details are provided [here](http://www.sencha.com/store/touch/).

Comment: Why use Google if you can also ask at SO? ;-)

Comment: Nope. What you're paying for is the support, not the framework. Sencha Touch is [free of charge](http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-10-ships-now-free/).

Comment: May be you should read more and not just the blog. They have customized commercial license for customers. But they have not provided any cost on website.. the cost I pointed to was support cost page.